# R: Change every 5th value in a column in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame uploaded from excel with 10 columns and 100 rows, and all the data is 0. Now I would like to change every 5th value in the second column to 1. Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: `df[5*(1:20),2] = 1`

Comment: Please save the rstudio tag for questions related to editor RStudio - for example if code runs on the command line but breaks in RStudio.

Comment: Thank you for the help! Fixed the tag now, Gregor.

Comment: `df[ rep(c(rep(FALSE, 4), TRUE), 20), 2] = 1`

Answer (score 1):

One approach using `seq` is `df[seq(from = 5, to = nrow(df), by = 5), 2] <- 1`